# Meaning of "Errors" graph in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform

Lately, we were experiencing issues with the Google Maps API. I just checked my Google Cloud Platform Dashboard and the "Errors" graph shows 100%.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what this value means? (The service seems to work again, but the value is staying on 100%.)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to:

1. Click on the API name **Maps Statics API** this will take you to that
   particular API Overview page
2. Click on **Metrics** (left menu)

That should show you several graphs see the one that says Errors by API method
to see which method is generating errors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps **Static** API can only be invalid requests, because it's for embedding Google Maps.